# Verifying Sampling Distribution of a Statistic

Tags: distributions, self-study, t-distribution

[image: Question]

In the given question, I can easily show that option A and C are true but i am not sure about option B.

I know that |$X_2$ +$X_3$| can be written as $($$(X_2 + X_3)^2$$)^{1/2}$ and then it can be used to make a Chi-Square Variable of 1 degree of freedom.

But is this correct?

Comment: How *exactly* could $|X_2+X_3|$ be used to make a chi-squared variable? That detail might help you answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, because $X_2+X_3\sim N(0,2)\implies\left(\frac{X_2+X_3}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2\sim \chi^2_1$, independently of $X_1\sim N(0,1)$, $$\frac{\sqrt 2X_1}{|X_2+X_3|}=\frac{X_1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{X_2+X_3}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2}}\sim t_1$$

Alternatively, since $\frac{X_2+X_3}{\sqrt 2}\sim N(0,1)$, independently of $X_1\sim N(0,1)$,

$$\frac{X_1}{\left|\frac{X_2+X_3}{\sqrt 2}\right|}\sim \mathsf{Cauchy}(0,1)$$